# Determining if a file is parsed by Qt Creator (CUDA Syntax highlighting)

Tags: cuda, ide, qt-creator

I switched recently from Visual Studio to Qt Creator. I am still using the Visual Studio Compiler on Windows as CUDA has this as a dependency. CUDA uses some functions and keywords that are only valid when compiled by nvcc, so I did a workaround in Visual Studio to enable syntax highlighting for CUDA files:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __INTELLISENSE__

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

#define __CUDACC__

#include <device_functions.h>

#endif
```

This works in Visual Studio as the preprocessor macro `__INTELLISENSE__` is only defined when Visual Studio itself parses the file, not during compilation. Now I wanted to know if there is also a macro that Qt Creator defines during parsing so that this workaround for coding CUDA still works.

Thanks
Sven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#ifdef Q_CREATOR_RUN
// ...
#endif
```

Comment: please elaborate on the solution, rather than throwing a code snippet and call it an answer. this will help others getting the principal behind it, leading to a more deep understanding.